# Removing Parenthesis After A Character

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, plsql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to remove the Parenthesis and its contents after a comma for an Employee Name Field.

I cant seem to get the syntax right to remove special characters and numbers AFTER the first comma. Then i would like to rearrange them if possible to show First Name then Last Name.

*Employee Name*

```
Doe (Developer), John(123456)
```

I can get as far as this:

```
Doe (Developer), John ()
Doe , John

translate(column_1, 'a0123456789', 'a') as employee_name,
 regexp_replace(employee_name, '\\([^)]*\\)')
```

I'd like to be able to get to

```
Doe (Developer), John
```

but the perfect scenario would be

```
John (Developer) Doe
```

Comment: You could achieve it by using 3 x `REGEXP_SUBSTR` commands to extract each relevant part, and then join them together again.

Comment: Have you considered doing this by [Creating a user-defined function - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/user-defined-functions.html)?

Answer (score 1):

We can try using `REGEXP_REPLACE` with capture groups:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(employee_name, '^(\\w+).*?(\\(.*?\\)),[ ]*(\\w+).*$', '$3 $2 $1') AS first_last
FROM yourTable
```

Here is a working [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O3NSaa/3).

Answer (score 0):

I think i found an answer. thanks for all the help though!
select

replace(translate(employee_name, 'a0123456789', 'a'), '()', '') as employee_name2,
split_part(replace(translate(employee_name, 'a0123456789', 'a'), '()', ''),',',2) ||' '|| split_part(replace(translate(employee_name, 'a0123456789', 'a'), '()', ''),',',1)
as employee_name3,

from mytable